# Is there a way to explicitly write a elixir function to be tail call optimised?

Tags: recursion, optimization, clojure, elixir, tail-recursion

In Clojure for example you can use the [recur](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(recur%20exprs*)) especial form to explicit the intention to use non-stack-consuming recursive calls, and is verified by the compiler. As it's wrote in the Clojure [docs](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--(recur%20exprs*)):

> "recur in other than a tail position is an error", 
>   "recur is functional and its use in tail-position is verified by the compiler"

In elixir you can define a function as a series of clauses, with recursions calls between them. Is there a way to know for sure that the defined function is going to be tail call optimised?

Comment: Simple answer is calls are TCO in Erlang and Elixir unless you code them in such a way as to prevent it.  Basically if you do anything with the return value of the function, for example adding 1 to the return value, then it's not TCO because a stack has to be maintained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler doesn't optimize a **function**. It optimizes a **call** to that function. It may be the call to the same function inside it, it may be a call to different function, it doesn't matter.

...which isn't the case with Clojure, where `recur` can only return execution to the **latest** "recursion point" (be it `loop` or `fn`) which makes mutual recursion impossible without "help from the outside", such as a [trampoline](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/trampoline). It's more like a *bandaid* than a solution, but the problem is too big and a proper solution would require too much.

Yes, there is a way to make sure it gets optimized in Elixir: *it needs to be an actual [**tail call**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)*. That's all.

> In computer science, a tail call is a subroutine call performed as the final action of a procedure.

This can easily be determined by visually inspecting the code.

If Clojure were to work this way, the following two definitions would be equivalent:

```
(defn x [] (x))     ; <- StackOverflowError if called
(defn x [] (recur)) ; <- hangs if called
```

But if you want to **enforce** this and fail otherwise, you have to do it either:

- before compilation, e. g. with static code analyis using some markings for "desired TCO"
- before deployment, e. g. with tests that would trigger stack overflow

The latter seems more practical, easiest with pure functions.

I haven't found any existing solutions that do that.

Comment: Can you confirm if a tail call must he just a a function call and nothing else: i.e. if the last statement is `funt(n)` that's a tail call if it is `1 + funct(n)` that will not be tail optimised.

Comment: @DavidC if there are any computations on the return value (e. g. adding 1 to the return value)  then a new stack frame must be created and the call cannot be TCO.